# Community Bulletin box is hard to read

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The new "community bulletin" box has light orange text on a light blue background, which is fairly difficult to read:

[image: Screenshot of the box]

Comment: I was all, like, wait, what, it looks fine to me. Then I realized I was looking at the one over → right here on meta. The one on the main site _is_ bad.

Comment: We'll get a fix rolled out shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fix for this was deployed a few days ago. (: